# Traffic/roadworks record for Greater London

Tags: data-request, uk, traffic

I am looking for a dataset which provides a record of roadworks operations in and around London. Alternatively, I might be able to make use of a log of traffic/congestion much like what Google maps provide for road trips. Please let me know if you are aware of such a record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the data here -:

https://www.datazar.com/file/fc210d5e3-f0a6-489a-9fe0-e06f3da140cb

P.S - I work for datazar, an open data library, where people can share, discover and work with data.

Comment: This is useful. I already searched for data from the Highways Agency but I didn't get these results.